# After upgrading to 22.04 my laptop does not shut down properly

Tags: keyboard, power-management, 22.04, shutdown

When I was using the previous ubuntu LTS on this laptop, it would shutdown cleanly. The keyboard and power lights would extinguish themselves, and I could reboot by pressing the power button.

However, after upgrading to 22.04, my laptop no longer shuts down cleanly. Instead, it leaves the keyboard and power lights on. To reboot, I first have to hold the power button down for several seconds to turn the lights off, and then have to press the power button again to reboot.

Comment: some services might take a looong time for stopping, press ESC to see what's taking so long, maybe you can try to fix it, or if you don't care, edit `/etc/systemd/system.conf` and add `DefaultTimeoutStopSec=30s` for example. it will then only wait for 30 seconds for a service to stop

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it had no effect. Twenty minutes later and the power LED is still on, and the laptop got really hot.

Comment: I erased the machine and reinstalled 20.04. Everything is back to normal.